# Can first order linear PDE be elliptic?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In Corollary 3.1.15 of Hormander's Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators, he proves that if a distribution $u \in \mathcal D'(\Bbb R)$ satisfies $u' + a u = f \in C(\Bbb R)$, then $u \in C^1(\Bbb R)$ in the classical sense. Can this be generalized to several variables? Let's say that
$$
P = \sum_{i = 1}^n a ^i(x)\partial_i + b(x)
$$
is a first order partial differental operator with smooth coefficients. If in the weak sense we have $Pu = f \in X$ for some space $X$, when does it follow that $u \in X$? For instance, if $X = C_0^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$, I know I can solve $Pv = f$ to obtaine a smooth $v$, and $v$ would also be a weak solution, but I cannot see a way of showing that $u = v$ because I have no initial conditions for $u$.

Answer (score 1):

No, first order equations you describe are known as [transport equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation). These are in general hyperbolic and do not preserve regularity of the right-hand side.

To see this, suppose $n=2$, and denote the variables by $(t,x)$. Then assuming the $a^i$ are constant with one non-zero and $b=0$, we can reduce to the form
$$ \partial_tu + c \partial_xu = 0. $$
This admits solutions of the form
$$ u(t,x) = \phi(x-ct) $$
for arbitrary $\phi$; in particular $u$ may be as irregular as you wish by choosing $\phi$ to be irregular.

The above construction can be generalised to higher dimensions. In general equations of this type, one can transport the initial data via [the method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). In this case, the (ir)regularity of the initial data is preserved as it is transported along these characteristic curves. The validity of this method relies on the associated principal symbol
$$ \sigma_P(x,\xi) = \sum_{i=1}^n a^i(x) \xi_i $$
vanishing along certain hypersurfaces. For general differential operators, ellipticity is often defined to require that $\sigma_P(x,\xi) \neq 0$ for all $x$ and all $\xi \neq 0$, which is evidently never satisfied for first order operators.

As an aside, first order *systems of equations* may be elliptic, such as with the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).